# Rotating between three headers using jquery's .replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is designed to rotate between three different h3 elements. It currently works, but is pretty sloppy looking. When I eventually mimic this for a p and an img element, it will be way longer than it needs to be. I'm fairly new to jQuery, so I'm looking for a little cleanup and polish.

HTML:

```
<h3 id="subtitle1">first subtitle</h3>
```

jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if($("#subtitle1").length) {
        $('#subtitle1').replaceWith("<h3 id='subtitle2'>second subtitle</h3>");
    } else if($("#subtitle2").length) {
        $('#subtitle2').replaceWith("<h3 id='subtitle3'>third subtitle</h3>");
    } else if($("#subtitle3").length) {
        $('#subtitle3').replaceWith("<h3 id='subtitle1'>first subtitle</h3>");
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248721/jquery-replacewith-fade-animate
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075664/making-a-simple-jquery-carousel

Comment: What do you mean with "sloppy"? You have a lot of html inside your javascript code, this is bad habit. I would place all three titles in the html and hide two of them by giving them a class "hidden". In jquery you can use addClass("hidden") and removeClass("hidden")

Comment: Also check http://designscrazed.com/free-responsive-jquery-carousel-slider-plugins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example - you'll have to modify it to suit your exact needs.

**HTML**

```
<h3 id="header-title">This is some title text</h3>
<p id="header-text">This is some text</p>
<img id="header-image" src="./images/something.jpg" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var mods = [{
        title: "This is header text 1",
        text: "This is paragraph text 1",
        image: "./images/header-image-01.jpg"
    }, {
        title: "This is header text 2",
        text: "This is paragraph text 2",
        image: "./images/header-image-02.jpg"
    }, {
        title: "This is header text 3",
        text: "This is paragraph text 3",
        image: "./images/header-image-03.jpg"
    }];

var counter = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    counter = (counter + 1) % mods.length;

    $("#header-title").text(mods[counter].title);
    $("#header-text").text(mods[counter].text);
    $("#header-image").attr("src", mods[counter].image);

}, 20000);
```

It simply loops through all the changes you place in the array `mods`, making changes every 20 seconds.  Add/remove properties and change the function in the interval to suit your pages.

You can also expand the number of elements in the array as much as you like without breaking it.